# Android Viewpager How to save state of the page?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a fragment named QuoteFragment where i will display quote. I have created an activity named QuoteViewPager which will host the QutoeFragment. I have another activity and fragment for same quote for list view. If the user are in quote # 50 in view pager and if they go to listview and comes back to view pager again then View pager start displaying from Quote #1. I want to start Display view pager from Qutoe # 50. The following way i tried it but did not work.
In my Fragment Class:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(PAGE_ITEM((QuoteViewPager)getActivity()).getViewPager().getCurrenttem());


    }
```

Here getViewPager has the following code in my QuoteViewPager extends FragmentActivity class:

```
public ViewPager getViewPager(){

        if(quoteViewPager == null){
            quoteViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
            quoteViewPager.setId(R.id.quoteViewPager);
        }

        return quoteViewPager;
    }
```

And in the same fragment in onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) i have put the following code:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
        ((QuoteViewPager)getActivity()).getViewPager().setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(PAGE_ITEM,0));
}
```

When i debug it I found out that my PAGE_ITEM has 50 value but savedInstanceState is always null in onCreate method. 
Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Try overriding onRestoreInstanceState(...)

Comment: Hello @user1459497 Have you solve this problem?? I have the same issue,if you solve please can you help me Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, You need to place value as key,value pair in `Bundle`.
And the override `onRestoreInstanceState` to restore the state

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putInt("quoteNumber", PAGE_ITEM((QuoteViewPager)getActivity()).getViewPager().getCurrenttem());
}


@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  int quoteNumber = savedInstanceState.getInt("quoteNumber");
}
```